# PHP and MySQL WP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to accomplish two things here with this code. I am writing PHP directly into a WP page using the INSERT PHP Plugin.

1) Query the MySQL database and return the results from one column into four columns.

2) Make each result is its own hyperlink that directs the user to a new WP page that runs a new query on that page.

I am able to get the query to show results and even to turn those results into a dynamic hyperlink, however I cannot get the formatting down. Right now it just returns the result into one column. Here is what I have:

```
[insert_php]

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "login"; //edited for privacy
$password = "password"; //edited for privacy
$database = "database"; //edited for privacy

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

//get results from database
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT mine FROM mines ORDER BY mine");
$all_property = array();  //declare an array for saving property

//showing property
echo '<table class="data-table">
        <tr class="data-heading">';  //initialize table tag

while ($property = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {
    echo '<td>' . $property->name . '</td>';  //get field name for header
    array_push($all_property, $property->name);  //save those to array
}
echo '</tr>'; //end tr tag

//showing all data

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($all_property as $item) {
        echo "<td><a href='urlhere/$row[$item]'>".$row[$item]. "</a>"."</td>"; //get items using property value
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo "</table>";

[/insert_php]
```

Thanks for any help you can offer.

I'd like the results to look like this (each one as a hyperlink):

[Image link below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72qmE.png)

Comment: Your query only grab one column.  How do you expect to see 4 columns?

Comment: Can you show what format/out put you are expecting?

Comment: Eric - I'd like to format my results into four columns on the page.

Comment: Ravinder - please see link to image I added in original post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work this out. Still have not gotten the results to properly hyperlink but the array is filling in over four columns now. Here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT mine FROM mines ORDER by mine";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if ($result) { 
   $data = array(); 
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
      $data[] = $row['mine']; 
   } 
} 

if (is_array($data) && count($data)) { // if array's not empty, create HTML 

      //create a table & header row 
      $htmlout="<table><tr> 
         <th colspan='4'>Mine</th></tr> 
         <tr> 
      "; 

       $counter = 1; //keep count of data 

       foreach ($data as $mines) { 
         //table cell for datum 
         $htmlout .= "<td>$mines</td>\n"; 

         //rows of 4 
         if ($counter % 4 == 0) { 
             $htmlout .= "</tr>\n<tr>\n"; 
         } 
         $counter++; 
      } 
} 
$htmlout .= "</tr></table>"; 

echo $htmlout;
```